# How to get the Number of CPU to be used in Parallelism in execute dbms_mview.refresh

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, cpu, materialized-views

I'm using Oracle 10g 10.2.0.4 version.

I want to refresh my Materialized View in fast method with parallelism.

for the below type of CPU what will be the recommended number of Parallel CPU to be used ?

execute dbms_mview.refresh('XXARG_ACC_ANALYSIS',method=>'f','No.of CPU');

```
16:54:33 SQL> show parameter cpu;

NAME                                 TYPE                              VALUE
------------------------------------ --------------------------------- ------------------------------
cpu_count                            integer                           8
parallel_threads_per_cpu             integer                           2
```

Comment: There is no one good answer for that question. You should consider how DB is used during time when refresh will be performed what is query for MV and so on

Comment: Or how to get the degree of parallelism ?

Answer (score 0):

Given your CPU_count is 8, I assume you have 8 cores on your system. So that would be a good start. However, you will have to make sure you have resources available; ie not being consumed by another process/user. In addition, you will need to have sufficient IO bandwidth to keep the CPU's busy, if you are doing a lot of table scans.